# ST_Distance in Virtual Layer query not working on QGIS on Mac but on Windows

Tags: qgis, spatialite, mac, virtual-layer

I tried to use solution posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344909/get-median-distance-from-a-bunch-of-points-from-a-assigned-location-and-draw-buf/344945#344945), but ST_Distance in the Virtual Layer query doesn't work properly in Qgis (v3.2) on Mac, the result is showing blank while the same script is working properly in QGIS (v3.4) on Windows.

Here is my test script for virtual layer:

```
WITH distances AS(
  SELECT 
    s.id site_id,
    a.Mem_ID mem_id,
    ST_Distance(
            s.geometry, 
            a.geometry
            ) dist
  FROM site_a27 s
  CROSS JOIN A27_re a

)
SELECT * FROM distances
```

table for site_a27:

```
id,name,Response_X,Response_Y
1A27,bade,121.301412,24.968988
```

table for A27_re:

```
Mem_ID,Response_X,Response_Y
19960126000178,121.312175,24.987227
19960129000943,121.302705,24.978186
19960131001647,121.303628,24.957379
19960131002543,121.300855,24.984292
19960203000247,121.296974,24.968484
```

output of virtual layer on Mac:
[image: attribute table of virtual layer on Mac]

output of virtual layer on Windows:
[image: attribute table of virtual layer on Windows]

Information about my QGIS version on Mac:
[image]

How do I solve this in QGIS on Mac?

Comment: The [doc](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html) says "This function only supports Long/Lat coordinates, and will return NULL for any planar CRS". Double check the 2 layers projection

Comment: @JGH, That is the case when adding the boolean `True` for the *use_ellipsoid* parameter. Without that parameter: _"return the distance between geom1 and geom2 (always measured in CRS units)"_. But I agree with the check of the layers CRS.

Comment: Both layers are WGS84 as default and the results of dist field are still blank on Mac. Could that be a bug only on Mac?

Comment: I have added the [mac] tag to your post. Try with the following query: `SELECT 1 fid, ST_Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)'),GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')) dist;`. Does it return a distance in the table?

Comment: Is the fid in the query from layer b or layer a?

Comment: There is not a FROM clause in the query that I am proposing you to test, it is to test if the ST_Distance function works in Mac. I am creating a fid field with the 1 value in the output, just to have an identifier, but you can test: `SELECT ST_Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)'),GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')) dist;` . Does it return a distance in the table?

Comment: hi @Gabriel, nope, the dist field is blank in qgis on mac with provided code.

Comment: That is strange. Can you edit your post to include a screenshot of the _Help_ menu, _About_ window in Mac? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fo5P.png

Comment: Look at this message, maybe it can help you: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Website/issues/608#issuecomment-489320264

Comment: Hey @Gabriel, it is fixed by reinstall version 3.4, thanks!

Comment: @Pete, You are welcome, glad to know you could fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed by re-installing the newest version of QGIS (3.4).

The following link is to the bug reported about the SpatiaLite issue for the Homebrew installation: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29714.

The following link is to the change of installers for macOS in the QGIS Website: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Website/issues/608.